# Does a Firebase push key has to be written to db or as soon as one is computed the uniqueness is guaranteed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Does a push key need to be written to the Firebase database to stay unique in the future or is it considered taken as soon as its computed client side and if; for example,  it hasn't been written to database yet and another client (Client B) is generating a key might turn out to be the same one the client A has?

I hope it's clear what I'm asking.

Comment: I did not understand the question .. try to make it more clear and I will see if I can help you

Comment: [read this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) ,

Answer (score 2):

It will most likely be a GUID, meaning a global unique number and will never be generated again. (As soon as issued).

Have a look here: [link](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/14bj2z41xr/firebase-question-on-push-unique-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Just to attempt to reason it better; based on what I ready and understand, it doesn't seem to be a global mechanism to ensure they are unique other than the fact that the chance of it being computed twice is infinitesimal ([see here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)) plus the fact that part of each ID is computed based on server timeStamp. So basically, if there are two users creating pushIDs at the exact same server time (infinitesimally low chance) there is still a chance but its practically very close to 0 to have pushIDs identical because the second part of pushIDs are also made by a mechanism to ensure something of ~  1 in 2^120  chance of occurrence.

Combine the two segments and you have a practically 0 chance of re-occurance. However, mathematically is not 0, for those paranoid fellows like myself ;P
Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.